# Assigning nullable types to an imported .NET class in Wonderware Application Server

Tags: c#, nullable, wonderware

I'm having a problem assigning values to a nullable type in the Wonderware ArchestrA IDE (2012 R2).

My imported .NET class looks like this:

```
    public class TestObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> MyNullableInt { get; set; }

        public int MyInt { get; set; }
    }
```

I then import this into the Galaxy using Import -> Script Function Library.

My ArchestrA script then consists of literally, just this:

```
dim NT as NullTest.TestObject;
NT = new NullTest.TestObject;
NT.MyNullableInt = 3;
```

The script validates, but but assigning to `MyNullableInt` causes a script error to be logged in the management console:

ProdCapability_001.GetMESWOData: {0896E675-F7D7-4F77-9FD2-20477058E072}: JIT Compiler encountered an internal limitation.

.NET 4.5 is installed on the server. Can imported .NET classes in Wonderware Application Server not use Nullable types? Or have I missed something?

Comment: What happens when you change it to this: `NT.MyNullableInt = new Nullable<int>(3);`? Do you get that exception also when you use `NT.MyInt = 3;`?

Comment: When I do that I get, "Type 'Nullable' not found".

Comment: Then use `System.Nullable<int>(3);`.

Comment: Already did, now I get "Constructor overload not found"

Comment: [That's strange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwxxazwb.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have discovered that generics are not supported, which explains the bizarre "Constructor overload not found" message. From the ArchestrA IDE Help:

> Although QuickScript supports import libraries built with .NET CLR
>   version 2.0.50727, it does not support any of the new language
>   features introduced with .NET 2.0, such as generics.

So, looks like I need to create a class which supports the assignment of null for each .NET value type that I want to be able to assign null to, as opposed to using the Nullable class.

Answer (score 0):

Wonderware has some missing functionality (nulls, generics, exception handling, using statements). However, if I recall correctly you can use DBNull in some cases (for example, if you want a blank cell in a table or if you're writing a null value to a database).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx